# How can I stop using beta iOS on my iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm currently on the beta program on my iPhone. How can I stop using the beta versions and go back to the newest version of iOS (non-beta)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To opt out of getting future betas, delete the iOS beta profile. On iOS 10, this can be done as follows: Settings > General > Profile > Delete Profile.

This will not remove the installed beta. It appears, the easiest way you can go back to a non-beta version is by restoring a backup.

Some articles that may be useful:

- [Removing iOS beta profile](http://osxdaily.com/2016/06/19/remove-ios-beta-profile-certificate/)
- [Downgrading to iOS 9](http://osxdaily.com/2016/06/16/downgrade-ios-10-beta-to-ios-9/)